# Hiding/Displaying columns using jQuery, checkboxes, and local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I have a page where a user submits a query using MVC, and the user can select the columns that are shown using checkboxes. After the user selects the query parameters and columns to view, the user is then sent to another page where a roster of individuals are shown. Checkbox data is stored using local storage, and used on the roster page where there are also checkboxes that the user can use to hide or display columns. 
I have a working version, but the code looks awful and I think there is a better way to do this with less lines of code.

Here are the checkboxes used on the query page:

```
<div id="grpChkBox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="columnSelect" name="fullName" /> Full Name
  <input type="checkbox" class="columnSelect" name="type" /> Type
  <input type="checkbox" class="columnSelect" name="ID" /> ID Number
</div>
```

Here is the script used to select columns and set values in local storage:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
//Default is that all columns are selected
    $("#grpChkBox input:checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
    localStorage.setItem("fullName", 1);
    localStorage.setItem("type", 1);
    localStorage.setItem("ID", 1);

  $(function () {
      if (localStorage.getItem("fullName") !== null) {
          $("input[name='fullName']").attr("checked", "checked");
      }
  });
  $("input[name='fullName']").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {localStorage.setItem("fullName", 1);}
        else {localStorage.removeItem("fullName");}
  });

  $(function () {
      if (localStorage.getItem("type") !== null) {$("input[name='type']").attr("checked", "checked");}
  });
  $("input[name='type']").click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) { localStorage.setItem("type", 1); }
      else {localStorage.removeItem("type"); }
  });

  $(function () {
      if (localStorage.getItem("ID")== null) { $("input[name='ID']").attr("checked", "checked"); }
  });
  $("input[name='ID']").click(function () {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) { localStorage.setItem("ID", 1); }
      else { localStorage.removeItem("ID"); }
  });
```

As you can see, I am creating a function for each checkbox and corresponding column, and there should be a way that I can enumerate columns/checkbox to do this with less lines of code. Just not sure how.

This is the HTML for the roster that is generated on the next page:

```
<table class="MainContent" style="width: 100%;" id="rosterTable">
<tr>
  <th class="fullName" title="Full Name">Name</a></th>
  <th class="type" title="Type">Type</a></th>
  <th class="ID" title="ID Number">ID Number</a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name 1</td>
  <td>Type 1</td>
  <td>ID Number 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Name 2</td>
  <td>Type 2</td>
  <td>ID Number 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It also has the same checkboxes as the previous page:

```
<div id="grpChkBox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="columnSelect" name="fullName" /> Full Name
  <input type="checkbox" class="columnSelect" name="type" /> Type
  <input type="checkbox" class="columnSelect" name="ID" /> ID Number
</div>
```

And here's the script that reads local storage, and hides/displays columns after the roster is generated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Reads local storage and check or unchecks, hides/displays
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("fullName") !== null) {
        $("input[name='fullName']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
    else {
        var index = $("#rosterTable th").filter(".fullName").index();
        $("#rosterTable").find('tr :nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide();
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem("type") !== null) {
        $("input[name='type']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
    else {
        var index = $("#rosterTable th").filter(".type").index();
        $("#rosterTable").find('tr :nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide();
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem("ID") !== null) { $("input[name='ID']").attr("checked", "checked"); }
    else {
        var index = $("#rosterTable th").filter(".ID").index();
        $("#rosterTable").find('tr :nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide();
    }

//After roster is generated users can hide display columns
$(function () {
    var $chk = $("#grpChkBox input:checkbox");
    var $tbl = $("#rosterTable");
    var $tblhead = $("#rosterTable th");

    //$chk.prop("checked", true);


    $chk.click(function () {
        var colToHide = $tblhead.filter("." + $(this).attr("name"));
        var index = $(colToHide).index();
        $tbl.find('tr :nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Once again, this should be done with less lines of code than using a case for each column and checkbox. I need to deploy this solution to multiple pages with different columns, so I would like to do this with more dynamic code. I'm pretty sure this could be done with less lines of code.

All help is appreciated

Comment: what is your problem now?

Comment: The problem is that it looks like there are too many lines of code, which would make deployment of this solution to multiple reports cumbersome. There should be some way to enumerate the various checkboxes and columns, rather than creating multiple functions that call each one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution myself. Here's what I did:
First, I replaced localStorage with sessionStorage.
I replaced the section where I set each sessionStorage object explicitly with this:

```
var selected = [];
  $('#grpChkBox input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
          sessionStorage.setItem(($(this).attr('name')), 1);
      } else { sessionStorage.removeItem(($(this).attr('name'))); }
  });
```

I replaced all the functions for checking the each sessionStorage value and populating each checkboxes with:

```
for (var i = 0, len = sessionStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
      var key = sessionStorage.key(i);
      var value = sessionStorage[key];
      //document.write(key + " => " + value + "\n");
      if (sessionStorage.getItem(key) !== null) {
          $("input[name='" + key + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
      } 
  }
```

I replaced all the click functions for each checkbox with this:

```
$('#grpChkBox input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
      if ($(this.name).attr("checked")) {sessionStorage.setItem(this.name, 1); }
      else {sessionStorage.removeItem(this.name);}
  })
```

On the page where the roster is created, I replaced all the functions for checking the each sessionStorage value and populating each checkboxes with:

```
for (var i = 0, len = sessionStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
            var key = sessionStorage.key(i);
            var value = sessionStorage[key];
            //document.write(key + " => " + value + "\n");
            if (sessionStorage.getItem(key) !== null) {
                $("input[name='" + key + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
            }

        }
```

Instead of checking checkboxes that are checked, I am using unchecked values since the sessionStorage will have the corresponding keys/values removed. I replaced the many functions for determining which column is hidden with:

```
var selected = [];
        $('#grpChkBox input:checkbox:not(:checked)').each(function() {
            var index = $("#rosterTable th").filter("."+($(this).attr('name'))).index();
            $("#rosterTable").find('tr :nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide();
        });
```

That's it. The only thing that would make the over deployment of this simpler is if I could dynamically create checkboxes based on table header names.